# How to connect a modbus device to a volttron instance?

Tags: modbus, volttron

I have a modbus device connected using TCP/IP and I'm trying to get it connected to volttron so I can read/write data.

I stored the master driver configuration, the registry configuration and the device configuration.

modbustest-master-driver.agent
{
    "driver_scrape_interval": 0.05,
    "publish_breadth_first_all": false,
    "publish_depth_first": false,
    "publish_breadth_first": false
}

modbusttest.config
{
    "driver_config": 
        {"device_address": "10.0.1.7",
                      "port": 26,
                      "slave_id": 5},
    "driver_type": "modbus",
    "registry_config":"config://modbuspoints.csv",
    "interval": 60,
    "timezone": "US/Pacific",
    "heart_beat_point": "heartbeat"
}

I don't get any errors, but when i start a web browser and go to the volttron dashboard. My modbus device isn't there and it has this error "The following device topics were invalid and could not be added to the tree: devices/modbus/test"

[Error in Browser - using Firefox on Ubuntu Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxX6f.png)

Comment: Do you have a listener agent installed on your platform?  If yes you should see output from your device in the log.  Note this doesn't "fix" the issue you raise.  Right now the web interface is a bit flaky sometimes.  Refreshing browser sometimes helps etc.

Comment: Thanks! I'm now using the ListenerAgent and looking at the volttron.log file and can see the master-driver scraping both the fake-device and my modbus test device. How would I go about reading the data off of the modbus device?

Comment: To configure drivers you should refer to the configuration manual located: https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/core_services/drivers/driver_configuration/_Driver-Configuration.html